# 2 user inputs with condition and use in another method

Tags: java

I'm doing a school project which asks me to do the following in separate methods:

- start a main method and present the program
- ask for user to input 2 numbers (conditions a>b and both positive & if it's wrong to ask 3 times or finish program by letting user it's over)
- if conditions are ok, it should print first 2 consecutive number starting from a number, and last 2 consecutive numbers from b number.

I am dealing with several problems but biggest of them is that I can't use global variables so I should pass the numbers from a method to the other.
How can I do that?

The code I tried is

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Importar scanner

public class Eac4_001 {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Eac4_001 programa = new Eac4_001();
        programa.inicio();
    }

    public void inicio() {
        presentarPrograma();
        pedirNumeros();
        mostrarResultado();
    }

    public void presentarPrograma() {
        System.out.println("El programa pedirá dos números positivos.\n"
                + "El primero tiene que ser más pequeño que el segundo.\n"
                + "Luego enseñará los primeros y ultimos dos númberos del"
                + "rango conseguido.\n");
    }

    public void pedirNumeros() {
        int intentos = 3;
        boolean ok = false;
        int a = 0, b = -1;
        while (a > b && !ok) {
            System.out.print("Introduce un primer número: ");
            a = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Introduce un segundo número: ");
            b = scanner.nextInt();
            intentos = intentos - 1;
            if (intentos < 0) {
                ok = false;
            }
            System.out.println("Error, vuelve a introducir los números!");
        }
    }

    public void mostrarResultado() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Read your Java textbook. Or the Java tutorial. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: I did some research but as I seen, there is no way I can pass 2 int from a method to the other.

Comment: Your code is exactly the way you should NOT code in Java. I think you should read about object oriented programming.

Comment: @ALxALx : ofcourse you can pass as number of variables from one to another, but you can return just one.

Comment: Maybe that's why I'm starting to hate this. Can't really find the logic of it sometimes. At least not how they teach me.

Comment: I can provide you code, but promise you'll keep it as an reference only, and learn more about OOPs.

Comment: I guess I can manage with that. At least point me where am I doing wrong and give me an idea how it should be done. I would be more than thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a few changes in your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Importar scanner

public class Eac4_001 {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Eac4_001 programa = new Eac4_001();
        programa.inicio();
    }

    public void inicio() {
        presentarPrograma();
        pedirNumeros();
    }

    public void presentarPrograma() {
        System.out.println("El programa pedirá dos números positivos.\n"
                + "El primero tiene que ser más pequeño que el segundo.\n"
                + "Luego enseñará los primeros y ultimos dos númberos del"
                + "rango conseguido.\n");
    }

    public void pedirNumeros() {
        int retry = 0;
        int input1, input2;
        boolean ok = false;

        do {
            System.out.print("Introduce un primer número: ");
            input1 = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Introduce un segundo número: ");
            input2 = scanner.nextInt();

            if (input1 > 0 && input2 > 0) {
                ok = true;
                //call your method from here.
                mostrarResultado(input1, input2);
            } else {
                System.out.print("Invalid Input. Try again.");
                if (retry < 3) {
                    retry++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

        } while (!ok);
    }

    public void mostrarResultado(int input1, int input2) {
        //Do whatever you want to do, here with these variables
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To send numbers from one method to the other, you can **pass them as arguments** in to another function.

**Example**

```
public void method1(int a, int b){
    //code 
}
```

Above method receives two integer values as arguments.

[Link to learn about basics of methods in JAVA](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)

Another way to pass numbers from one method to another is by **returning the number from the method** and then calling that method from another method in which you want to pass the number.

If you only want to pass one number to another method, you can simply return it.

**Example**

```
public int method2(){
     int a = 20;
     return a; 
}
```

or if you want to pass more than one numbers, you can **store them in an array and then return that array**

**Example**

```
public int[] method3( )
{
      int[] x;

      x = new int[3];    // Create an array of 3 elements

      x[0] = 2;
      x[1] = 3;
      x[2] = 4;

      return( x );      
   }
```

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I could ask for the number and put them inside an array and pass it with return. Then take the array as an argument for the other.

Comment: returning a number or an array and passing a number or an array as an argument are two different things. If you return an array from a method, that returned array will be returned to where that particular method is called. If you pass an array as an argument in a method, you will need to make sure that you provide an array as an argument when you call that particular method which takes an array as an argument

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a method can only ever return one value. If Java didn't have this restriction, then you could write:

```
greeting();
int (a, b) = readNumbers();
output(a, b);
```

But since the second line is not valid Java, you have to do something else. The following comes very close:

```
greeting();
int[] numbers = readNumbers();
output(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
```

At the end of the `readNumbers` method, you can write:

```
return new int[] { first, second };
```

Note that the array is only used for the return value of the second method. In particular, it is not passed further to the third method. Doing that would be unnecessary because Java allows multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public Test() {

}

public static void main(String [] args){

    int [] myNumbers = new int[2];

    present();
    input(myNumbers);
    presentResult(myNumbers);

}

public static void present(){
    System.out.println("This is my presentation");
}

public static void input(int [] n){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2;i++){
        n[i] = scan.nextInt();
        while(n[i] < 0){
            System.out.println("Your number has to be higher then 0");
            n[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        if(n[1] < n[0] && i == 1){
            System.out.println("The 2:nd number needs to be greater the the first one");
            n[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
}

public static void presentResult(int [] n){
    Arrays.sort(n);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
}

}
```

So this works.

Comment: Your code seems okay but I tried to run it and it just ends.
About the conditions it's missing the condition where 2nd number must be bigger than 1st.